# Replacing for-loop in python when index is part of a array-manipulating function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop

I have a multidimensional `numpy` array which I need to modify such that its elements are modified as a function of the index of one of the dimensions only. I can of course do that with a `for` loop, as in the following simplified example

```
import numpy as np
a = np.ones( (2,10) )
for ii in range(a.shape[1]):
    a[:,ii] *= ii
```

If the array becomes very large, this might slow down the execution and I was wondering if there are some clever ways to avoid using a `for` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct another array to hold the scaling factors, then broadcast and multiply:

```
scale = np.arange(a.shape[1])
a *= scale
```